# Reading Data from file into 1D array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, struct

This is a ITP project that I have and would like some help on this question.

How to apply a Sequential search method to Read the data from the file called “mix.txt” containing the Country, Capital, Area and Population into a 1D array of the record type you defined.

This is the record type that I defined:

```
    struct Country
    {
        public string country;
        public string capital;
        public int area;
        public int population;
    }
    Country[] data = new Country[4];
```

The information is in this format:

```
Aland

Mariehamn

1552 

26300
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Please show your current code - teaching "how to read a text file", "how to declare list of objects like `List<Country>`", "how to write `while` loop" is generally outside scope of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can offer you this, but you should really try alone first:

```
string[] arrText;
string lineThreeHundred;

arrText = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test.txt");
int counter = 0;
List<Country> contries = new List<Country>();

while(counter < arrText.Length)
{
   Country curr =new Country();
   curr.country = arrText[counter];
   curr.capital = arrText[counter + 1];
   int.TryParse(arrText[counter + 2], out curr.area);
   int.TryParse(arrText[counter + 3], out curr.population);
   counter += 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data in the file is in one line split by space(for example) you can do this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
{
    string[] arr;
    arr = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ').ToArray();
}
```

of course, you can do loop of some lines, etc.